# 500 error with nginx loading django admin static files, but files load when making a request to the url

Tags: django, unix, nginx, django-staticfiles

I'm deploying a django web app to a nginx server running ubuntu

When I try to log into the app, which uses the default django auth system, I get a "Server Error (500)" message rendered

When I look at `/var/log/nginx/error.log` it shows the following message:

```
2016/10/11 22:35:53 [error] 16325#0: *42863 open()     "/path_to_app/app_name/static/admin/js/jquery.min.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ip, server: _, request: "GET /static/admin/js/jquery.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "domain_name.com", referrer: "http://nu-tab.me/accounts/login/?next=/"
2016/10/11 22:35:53 [error] 16325#0: *42865 open() "/path_to_app/app_name/static/admin/js/jquery.init.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ip, server: _, request: "GET /static/admin/js/jquery.init.js HTTP/1.1", host: "domain_name.com", referrer: "http://nu-tab.me/accounts/login/?next=/"
2016/10/11 22:35:53 [error] 16325#0: *42866 open() "/path_to_app/app_name/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: ip, server: _, request: "GET /static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js HTTP/1.1", host: "domain_name.com", referrer: "domain_name.com/accounts/login/?next=/"
```

However, when I load `domain_name.com/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js`, the file loads properly.

It's also worth noting that the `error.log` file has not been updated for recent requests.

Not very familiar with setting up servers so let me know if there's important info here that I'm leaving out.

nginx.conf:

```
user www-data;
worker_processes 4;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    # server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # nginx-naxsi config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-naxsi
    ##

    #include /etc/nginx/naxsi_core.rules;

    ##
    # nginx-passenger config
    ##
    # Uncomment it if you installed nginx-passenger
    ##

    #passenger_root /usr;
    #passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

In sites-enabled/django:

```
    upstream app_server { 
        server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0; 
    } 

    server { 
        listen 80 default_server; 
        listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on; 

        root /usr/share/nginx/html; 
        index index.html index.htm; 

        client_max_body_size 4G; 
        server_name _; 

        keepalive_timeout 5; 

        # your Django project's static files - amend as required 
        location /static/ { 
            alias /path_to_app/app_name/static/;  
        } 

        # your Django project's static files - amend as required
        location /media/ {
            alias /path_to_app/app_name/media/;
        }

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_pass http://app_server;
        }
    }
```

Relevant Django settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = '/path_to_app/app_name/static/'

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app_name', 'static'),
)
```

Comment: Can you post your nginx.conf?

Comment: Updated the post, it's in there now

Comment: ok, we need to see any conf files in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/` and `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` as well.

Comment: `conf.d/` is empty, added the other files

Comment: Kinda silly question but do you run `collectstatic` and point your nginx /static/ location to this folder with collected static?

Comment: Yup, they point to the same location. I am able to load a page that doesn't depend on any files in the /admin/ directory, I think it's once that's needed that the error occurs

Comment: Show us STATIC_URL and STATIC_ROOT please.

Comment: @AntonisChristofides added the settings to the post

Comment: Nginx says `/path_to_app/app_name/static/admin/js/admin/RelatedObjectLookups.js` does not exist, but you say that if you try to load it it loads. So, first, does the file exist or not? Second, what does nginx's `access.log` say for the failing request?

Also, are these really your settings, or is `path_to_app` a placeholder? You can mistype things if you change them instead of copy/pasting them.

Comment: The file does exit, and the corresponding `access.log` line is `[11/Oct/2016:21:33:49 -0400] "POST /accounts/login/?next=/ HTTP/1.1" 500 38 "domain_name.com/accounts/login/?next=/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36"`

Comment: The 500 may be unrelated to the static files. Set `DEBUG=True` and check the error message and traceback.